# Searching multiple tables in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have several different tables in my database(mySQL).

Here are the relevant coumns for the tables

table_tournaments

1. tournamentId
2. tournamnetName
3. tournamentStatus

table_tournament_results

1. tournamentId
2. playerId
3. playerName
4. playerRank
5. tournamnetParticipants

table_players

1. playerId
2. playerName

> The tournaments table contains the information about the tournament, the tournament results table shows the results from that table

I want to search the tournaments table by name and then with the returned results get the information from the tournament results table.

```
    SELECT * FROM `tournaments` `WHERE` `tournamentName` LIKE "%Query%"
```

I'm not sure how to go about this, maybe I need to do something via `PHP`, any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: tournamnetParticipants <- what's that?

Comment: It is a count of how many people participated in the tournament.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the results you want with a **join** operation.

This is an example of an **outer join**, returning all rows from `t` that have the string `'foo'` appearing as part of `tournament_name`, along with any matching rows from `r`.

A relationship between rows in the two tables is established by storing a **common value** in the `tournamentId` column of the two tables. The predicate in the `ON` clause specifies the condition that determines if a row "matches".

```
 SELECT t.tournamentId
      , t.tournamentName
      , t.tournamentStatus
      , r.playerId
      , r.playerName
      , r.playerRank
   FROM table_tournaments t
   LEFT
   JOIN table_tournament_results r
     ON r.tournamentId = t.tournamentId
  WHERE t.tournament_name LIKE '%foo%'
  ORDER
     BY t.tournamentId
      , r.playerId
```

The `t` and `r` that appear after the table names are table **aliases**, we can qualify references to the columns in each table by prefacing the column name with the table alias and a dot. This makes the column reference unambiguous. (In the case of `tournamentId`, MySQL doesn't know if you are referring to the column in `t` or `r`, so we qualify it to make it explicit. We follow this same pattern for *all* column references. Then, someone reading the statement doesn't need to wonder which table contains the column `playerId`.

Comment: What does the `LEFT` argument or clause do?

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN` specifies an **outer join** operation. It says that we want to return **all** rows from the table on the *left* side (`t`), along with any matching rows from the table on the *right* side (`r`). If there isn't a matching row in `r`, the row from `t` (the left side) is returned, but with NULL values in place of the columns from `r`. If every row returned from `t` has at least one matching row in `r`, then result is the same as an **inner join**. We'd only see a difference where rows are "missing" from `r`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Query may be like this

```
SELECT a.*, b.tournamnetName FROM table_tournament_results a 
left join table_tournaments on a.tournamentId=b.tournamentId
WHERE b.tournamnetName LIKE "%Query%"
```

Comment: The predicate in the WHERE clause effectively negates the "outerness" of the LEFT JOIN. (The conditional test guarantees us that no rows will be returned with a NULL value for `tournamentName`, so any NULL-valued rows from `b` created by the "outer join" will  be discarded, rendering this equivalent to an inner join.